# special character different window with linux

Tags: linux, windows, spring, special-characters

I have two projects, one in Windows and another one in Linux. I use the same database for both (oracle 10g),I have got an input file which consists of text that includes special characters (`ÁTUL ÁD`).
the program logic is like this: read input file data to database, on windows the data (including the special characters) is displayed correct, on Linux the special characters display other characters. As I already said, I use same database for both of them, could you give me some help?

The program is complex, it uses the Spring Batch Framework. Maybe the encoding causes the problem, but I have no idea how to solve it. I am using Linux for the first time.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I find one solution which works for me is that you have to use UTF-8 encoding. All for Windows,Linux and Database.